# temporary object creation in copy constructor

Tags: c++

I am reading about copy constructor in C++

It was mentioned that an object is passed usuing call by value and return by values constructs a temporary objects that are never seen by the user. My understanding is that when we call by val for example

```
myclass b;

void myfunc(myclass c) {}  //c(b) copy constructor is called.
```

Where temporary object is created?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `where`? Scope, storage, conceptually?

Comment: You mean where is storage allocated? Usually on the stack, but the compiler may optimize it for small POD types (register allocation)

Comment: No, call by val doesn't need temporaty object creation.

Comment: See also http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/09/your-next-assignment/

Answer (score 1):

The copy is created in the function scope of `myfunc()`. That is, `c` is in scope of the entire function, which includes (and is slightly larger than) the function body. The copy is destroyed when the function returns, i.e. at the semicolon of `myfunc(b);`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of pass-by-value, a *copy* is made into the argument (rather than the temporary), so in the particular code in your example, there will be two objects:

```
myclass b;
myfunc( b ); // b is copied to argument "c" by means of the copy constructor
```

In the case of return by value, things are a bit more complex, in the code:

```
type f() {
   type tmp;
   return tmp;     // copies into temporary (again, copy constructor)
}
int main() {
   type x = f();   // copies from temporary into x (copy constructor)
   x = f();        // copies from temporary into x (assignment operator)
}
```

there are in theory 3 objects of type `type`. The compiler will create space for a `type` object before calling `f` in a location that is defined by the calling convention (this will be where the temporary is created), then the function is called and `tmp` is created inside `f`, it gets copied to the temporary in the return statement. Finally the temporary is copied to the `x` variable in `main`.

In many cases, though, the compiler can optimize away the temporaries by carefully choosing the locations of the variables. Most compilers will be able to optimize 2 of the 3 objects away in the previous example.

For a longer description you can read these:

- http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html
- http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html